# Como não serializar alguns atributos em chamadas RESTful com Jersey e Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialização, jersey, jackson

Estou usando a biblioteca Jersey em conjunto com a biblioteca Jackson para usar web services do tipo REST. Nas chamadas, eu geralmente uso o seguinte código que transforma uma determinada entidade em um JSON a ser enviado no corpo da requisição.

```js
Map<String, Object> response = api.request().post(Entity.json(entidade), Map.class);
```

O ponto é que existem alguns atributos na `entidade` a ser enviada que eu gostaria que não fossem serializados como JSON na requisição e ficassem ausentes dela.

Existe alguma `annotation` ou coisa do tipo no qual seja possível determinar atributos que não deverão ser serializados neste tipo de requisição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ignorar um atributo na serialização, usei a annotation `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore` da própria biblioteca Jackson. Ela deve ser colocada no atributo a ser ignorado conforme o seguinte exemplo:

```
@JsonIgnore
private MeuObjeto objeto;
```